# Selenium can't locate xpath ofof button facebook post in a group

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to kick button posting in a group facebook using xpath. I got the xpath from google chrome dev mode (right click and copy xpath). The xpath I got is:
//*[@id="mount_0_0_7g"]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFx1.png)/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFx1.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFx1.png)/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFx1.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFx1.png)/div/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFx1.png)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFx1.png)/span

When I try to find it in gogole chrome, it finds the xapth just fine as shown in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFx1.png)

But Selenium throws an exception.
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

The code snippet I am using is as follows-

```
driver.get(url_grfb)
btn_up =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mount_0_0_7g"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span')
btn_up.click()
sleep(3)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just because that element exists when you visit the website in Chrome doesn't mean it exists when you visit the website in Selenium. Facebook can send you back different HTML. Also Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So don't be surprised when you get banned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code to post in any facebook group. This worked perfectly for me in windows.

Important things to note:

1. download webdriver for chrome and keep it in a folder named 'SeleniumDriver' in C drive. So it's path will be C:/SeleniumDriver/chromedriver.exe
2. In main don't forget to provide your facebook email, facebook password, facebook group id where you want to post and text you want to post.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


class PostToFacebook(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r";C:/SeleniumDriver"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(PostToFacebook, self).__init__()
        self.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.maximize_window()

    def login(self, fb_mail, fb_pass):
        url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'
        self.get(url)

        email = self.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
        email.send_keys(fb_mail)

        password = self.find_element(By.ID, 'pass')
        password.send_keys(fb_pass)

        login = self.find_element(By.NAME, 'login')
        login.click()

    def openFacebookGroup(self, group_id):
        new_url = f'https://www.facebook.com/groups/{group_id}'

        self.execute_script("window.open('');")

        self.switch_to.window(self.window_handles[1])
        self.get(new_url)

    def sendPost(self, post_text):
        write_something = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='b6ax4al1 lq84ybu9 hf30pyar om3e55n1']")
        write_something.click()

        create_post = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='_1mf _1mj']")
        create_post.send_keys(post_text)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page_source, 'html.parser')
        all_pc = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': re.compile("^mount_0_0_")})
        id_ = str(all_pc[0].get('id'))
        xpath = '//*[@id="' + id_ + '"]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div'
        post = self.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
        post.click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst = PostToFacebook()
    inst.login('YOUR_EMAIL','YOUR_PASSWORD')
    inst.openFacebookGroup('GROUP_ID_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_POST')
    inst.sendPost('TEXT_YOU_WANT_TO_POST')
```